# Python 3 dictionary update sequence element error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple `Def` so I can append my `json` file easily. I cant get the value(s) to work no matter how I try.

At the top I'm using

```
def AppendPersonal_data(X,Y):
    with open( username +'.json') as f:
        keymaster= X,Y 
        Personal_data = json.load(f)
        Personal_data.update(keymaster)
        with open(username + '.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(Personal_data, f)
```

Then on my button press in my menu I have

```
choice = input()
random_number = "1"
if choice == "1":
    if random_number == choice:
        now = str(datetime.now()) 
        print("YOU PICKED CORRECT!! ")
    else:
        print("YOU PICKED WRONG!! ")
    AppendPersonal_data(random_number,now)
```

No matter what I try I always end up with a :

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code - one being what throws your error - you're trying to update a dictionary (`Personal_data`) with a tuple (`keymaster`). You should be updating your dictionary as: `Personal_data[X] = Y`

But more importantly, you should not open two file handles to the same file at the same time - instead update the already opened file:

```
import json

def append_personal_data(username, x, y):
    with open(username + ".json", "r+") as f:
        personal_data = json.load(f)
        personal_data[x] = y
        f.seek(0)  # rewind
        f.truncate()  # clear the file content
        json.dump(personal_data, f)
```

Comment: After adjusting the capitalization to match, I'm still getting an error.
Personal_data[X] = Y
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: Don't pass a `set` (or any [mutable type](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/)) as `x` to the function because it cannot be stored as a key in a dictionary.  The above function will work with your `input` block, but if you're using it for something else you didn't state that in your original question. Also, do not capitalize and match with underscores, it's considered ugly by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) which most Python developers follow.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of messing with it I've gotten this to work
At the top

```
def AppendPersonal_data(X):
    with open( username +'.json') as f: 
        Personal_data = json.load(f)
        Personal_data.update(X)
        with open(username + '.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(Personal_data, f)
```

and then for the button press

```
    choice = input()
        random_sound = "1"
        if choice == "1":
            now = str(datetime.now())
            if random_sound == choice: 
                print("YOU PICKED CORRECT!! ")
                guess1= { ''+ str(datetime.now())+'' : ''+ str(random_sound) + '_Y' }
            else:
                guess1= { ''+ str(datetime.now())+'' : ''+ str(random_sound) + '_X' }
                print("YOU PICKED WRONG!! ")

            print (guess1)
            AppendPersonal_data(guess1)
```

I switched the datetime and random_sound values, but switching them back works the same. 
Sorry about all the ugliness. This is my 3rd day working with Python. So like 15h. 
Thank you guys for the tips. If there's a way to optimize this, please let me know.